# How can i separate this "£232.69" value without a currency symbol? I need this value to be 232.69

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, split, automation

```
String Total = driver.findElement(By.xpath("wwwww")).getText();
```

I will get the Value £232.69 from the above code. Now I want to split the separate the Value without that Currency Symbol. Like 232.69.
So that I can compare this value with another one.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("wwwww")).getText().substring(1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you any first number (integer or not, matching expression someNumbers + optional(dot + someNumbers)) occuring in string s as a string:

```
    String s = "&21.37";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)?)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    m.matches();
    String s = m.group(1)
```

You can then extract it as follows:

```
    Double d = Double.valueOf(s)
```

**Here is updated code:** , @kripindas

```
String s = "&1,221.37";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*([0-9]*,?([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*))?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
m.matches();
String s_num = m.group(1).replace(",", "");
System.out.println(s_num);
Double d_num = Double.valueOf(s_num);
System.out.println(d_num);
```

Note that this will match:

"&1,234.56",
 "$123,4.5678",
 "JP234,123.12"
and convert them to (correspondingly):
1234.56
1234.5678
234123.12

Comment: Thanks for the above code.Now I have a situation that I have to convert £1,310.12 this value like 1310.12. ie by removing the Currency symbol and comma. Can you please help me with this.@piezol

Comment: You can learn more about regular expressions in java [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).
I can't test this now, but this one could work:
(i posted answer in another comment)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .substring() js function for doing this. you can get more details from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

use th following

String Total = driver.findElement(By.xpath("wwwww")).getText().substring(1);

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out a few minutes ago.

```
price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.teaser-pricing div.pricing").text

print(price.split()[0].replace('$', ''))
```

This will split it from the first index and replace what you want from the text in the second part.